# Problemas al iniciar sesión con Ajax en servidor

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery, ajax

Mi problema es el siguiente:

He hecho un pequeño sistema, el cual funciona perfectamente en local (he usado php 7.0 y mysql, para construirlo, haciendo uso de Xampp), pero cuando lo he subido a un hosting gratuito para hacer pruebas no me ha permitido iniciar sesión. Cuando intento hacerlo, no hace absolutamente nada, la consola no me detecta ningún error, de hecho sale como si la respuesta obtenida fue exitosa pero el sistema no me inicia, no hace la debida redirección a la pagina principal.

Ya he usado ese host gratuito antes para probar mis desarrollos y todo sin problemas (y trabajando con Ajax igualmente). He revisado el codigo y no he encontrado ningun error.

Aqui les dejo el codigo de formulario del index.html:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <!-- Required meta tags -->
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

              <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

       </head>
     <body>
       <div class="container-fluid">

         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4" id="#formulario">

                <div class="form-title">
                     <img src="img/backgrounds/logo.png" class="img-fluid" width="100%"; alt="Responsive image">
                    </div>
                      <br><br>
                      <div id="form" class="form-body">
                           <form role="form" method="post" id="frmIngresar" name="frmIngresar">

                              <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="userinput">

                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class='fas fa-user'></i></div>
                                </div>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-username" name="form-username" required="" placeholder="Usuario">

                                          </div>

                                  <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="passinput">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                  <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="form-password" name="form-password" placeholder="Contraseña">

                                      </div>
                                        <br>
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md btn-block" id="acceder"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Inicia Sesión</button>
                                     </form>
                                       <br>
                                        <center><a href="#"><b>¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?</b></a></center>
                                        <center><p><b>¿Aun no usas E-V? </b></p></center>
                                        <center><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" id="registro">Pruebalo Gratis</a></center>


                                        <div class="footer">
                                           <center><p>Copyright <i class="fa fa-copyright"></i> 2018 E-V.</p></center>
                               <input type="hidden" id="alerta" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                               </div>

                                 <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8" id="imagen">

                                 <a href="https://ibb.co/bN7XTy"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/hmCz8y/fondo_Index.png" alt="fondo_Index" border="0" width="100%" height="100%"></a>


                           </div>
                                  </div>

                             </div>


                 <div class="modal fade" id="ModalSucursales" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalSucursalesTitle" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title" id="ModalSucursalesTitle">Bienvenido, <span id="nombreUsuario"></span></h3>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                 </button>
               </div>
              <div class="modal-body"> 

                 <div class="col-md-12">

          <!-- Horizontal Form -->
                  <div class="box box-info" id="listaSucursales">
                 <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h4 class="box-title">Elija la Sucursal a la cual quiere acceder:</h4>
            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
            <!-- form start -->

              <div class="box-body">
              <div class="box" id="cuerpoSucursales">

            <div class="box-body no-padding">

              <table class="table table-hover" id="tblSucursal">

                <thead>

                  <tr>                      
                  <th>Opcion</th>
                  <th>Sucursal</th>
                  <th>Logo</th>
                  </tr>

                </thead>

                <tbody id="Sucursal">

                </tbody>

              </table>
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
          </div><!-- /.box -->


          </div><!-- /.box -->
          <!-- general form elements disabled -->
          </div>

        </div><!--/.col (right) -->

           </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                 <a type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="CerrarSesion()">Cancelar acceso al sistema.</a>
                </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
                 </div>

               <script src="public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- <script src="public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

            <script src="public/js/icheck.min.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                   jQuery(document).ready(function() { 


        $("form#frmIngresar").submit(IngresarSistema);

        function IngresarSistema(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var user = $("#form-username").val();
            var pass = $("#form-password").val();

            $.getJSON("ajax/UsuarioAjax.php?op=IngresarSistema", {user: user, pass: pass}, function(r) {
                if (r) {

                  if (r.superadmin == "A") 
                  {

                    comprobarSuscripcion();

                    var alerta = $("#alerta").val();

                    AccesoEmpleado(r.idusuario, r.idsucursal, r.idempleado, r.empleado, r.tipo_documento, r.tipo_usuario, r.num_documento, r.direccion, r.telefono, r.foto, r.logo, r.email, r.login, r.razon_social, r.idempresa, r.Empresa, r.mnu_almacen, r.mnu_compras, r.mnu_ventas, r.mnu_mantenimiento, r.mnu_seguridad, r.mnu_consulta_compras, r.mnu_consulta_ventas, r.mnu_admin, alerta);

                  }
                  else if (r.superadmin == "S") 
                  {

                    comprobarSuscripcion();

                  $("#nombreUsuario").html(r.empleado);

                  $("#ModalSucursales").modal('show');
                     $("#ModalSucursales").modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: true});

                    ListadoIngresos();


                  }


                } else {
                    bootbox.alert("Usuario o Contraseña incorrecta");
                    $("#form-username").val("");
                    $("#form-password").val("");
                    $("#form-username").focus();
                }
            });  
        }


                      function ListadoIngresos(){ 
                     $.post("ajax/SucursalAjax.php?op=listSucursalEmp", function(r){
                       $("#Sucursal").html(r);

                      });
                      };

                      });

            function comprobarSuscripcion() {

                    var op = 'ComprobarSuscripcion';

                    _ajax("ajax/SuscripcionAjax.php", {op:op})
                    .done( function (info) {

                            console.log(info); 

                          if (info !== 0) {

                       if (info[0].estado == "B") 
                    {


                       $("#alerta").val("1");

                       }

                      if (info[0].estado == "S" || info[0].estado == "SP") 
                    {

                           $("#alerta").val("0");

                        }

                   }

                        if (info == 0) 
                      {


                      $("#alerta").val("0");

                      }


                          });
                    }



                          function _ajax(url, data) {

                     var ajax = $.ajax({
                        "method" : "POST",
                        "url" : url,
                        "data" : data,
                        "dataType" : "json"
                         })

                        return ajax;
                          }

        //funcion para acceder al escritorio
            function Acceder(idusuario, idsucursal, idempleado, empleado, tipo_documento, tipo_usuario, num_documento, direccion, telefono, foto, logo, email, login, razon_social, idempresa, Empresa, mnu_almacen, mnu_compras, mnu_ventas, mnu_mantenimiento, mnu_seguridad, mnu_consulta_compras, mnu_consulta_ventas, mnu_admin){
               var alerta = $("#alerta").val();
          var data = { 
        idusuario : idusuario,
        idsucursal : idsucursal,
        idempleado : idempleado,
        empleado : empleado,
        tipo_documento : tipo_documento,
        tipo_usuario : tipo_usuario,
        num_documento : num_documento,
        direccion : direccion,
        telefono : telefono,
        foto : foto,
        logo : logo,
        email : email,
        login : login,
        razon_social : razon_social,
        idempresa : idempresa,
        Empresa: Empresa,
        mnu_almacen : mnu_almacen,
        mnu_compras : mnu_compras,
        mnu_ventas : mnu_ventas,
        mnu_mantenimiento : mnu_mantenimiento,
        mnu_seguridad : mnu_seguridad,
        mnu_consulta_compras : mnu_consulta_compras,
        mnu_consulta_ventas : mnu_consulta_ventas,
        mnu_admin : mnu_admin,
        alerta : alerta
             };
          $.post("ajax/UsuarioAjax.php?op=IngresarPanel", data, function(r){
            $(location).attr("href", "Escritorio.php");
              });
               }

              function AccederSuperAdmin(idempleado, idusuario, idsucursal, estadoAdmin, empleado, tipo_documento, direccion, telefono, foto, email, login, idempresa, Empresa, mnu_almacen, mnu_compras, mnu_ventas, mnu_mantenimiento, mnu_seguridad, mnu_consulta_compras, mnu_consulta_ventas, mnu_admin, logo){
                 var alerta = $("#alerta").val();
                  var data = { 
        idempleado : idempleado,
        idusuario : idusuario,
        idsucursal : idsucursal,
        estadoAdmin : estadoAdmin,
        empleado : empleado,
        tipo_documento : tipo_documento,
        direccion: direccion,
        telefono : telefono,
        foto : foto,
        email : email,
        login : login,
        idempresa : idempresa,
        Empresa : Empresa,
        mnu_almacen : mnu_almacen,
        mnu_compras : mnu_compras,
        mnu_ventas : mnu_ventas,
        mnu_mantenimiento : mnu_mantenimiento,
        mnu_seguridad : mnu_seguridad,
        mnu_consulta_compras : mnu_consulta_compras,
        mnu_consulta_ventas : mnu_consulta_ventas,
        mnu_admin : mnu_admin,
        logo: logo,
        alerta : alerta
                };
              $.post("ajax/UsuarioAjax.php?op=IngresarPanelSuperAdmin", data, function(r){
            $(location).attr("href", "Escritorio.php");
                  });
                }

            function AccesoEmpleado(iduser, idsuc, idemp, empl, tipo_doc, tipo_u, num_doc, direccion, telefono, foto, logo, email, login, razon_social, idempresa, Empresa, mnu_almacen, mnu_compras, mnu_ventas, mnu_mantenimiento, mnu_seguridad, mnu_consulta_compras, mnu_consulta_ventas, mnu_admin, alerta) {

          var data = {idusuario:iduser, idsucursal:idsuc, idempleado:idemp, empleado:empl, tipo_documento:tipo_doc, tipo_usuario:tipo_u, num_documento:num_doc, direccion:direccion, telefono:telefono, foto:foto, logo:logo, email:email, login:login, razon_social:razon_social, idempresa:idempresa, Empresa:Empresa, mnu_almacen:mnu_almacen, mnu_compras:mnu_compras, mnu_ventas:mnu_ventas, mnu_mantenimiento:mnu_mantenimiento, mnu_seguridad:mnu_seguridad, mnu_consulta_compras:mnu_consulta_compras, mnu_consulta_ventas:mnu_consulta_ventas, mnu_admin:mnu_admin, alerta:alerta};

                $.post("ajax/UsuarioAjax.php?op=IngresoEmpleado", data, function(r){
            $(location).attr("href", "Escritorio.php");
          });

            }

                  function CerrarSesion() 
                    {

           $(location).attr("href", "ajax/UsuarioAjax.php?op=Salir");      

              }

                 </script>
               </body>
             </html>
```

este es el codigo del archivo php que se encarga de procesar la petición:

```
          case "IngresarSistema":

        $user = $_REQUEST["user"];
        $pass = $_REQUEST["pass"];

        $query = $objusuario->Ingresar_Sistema($user, md5($pass));
        $fetch = $query->fetch_object();

        if(isset($fetch)){

            $_SESSION["idusuario"] = $fetch->idusuario;
            $_SESSION["idempleado"] = $fetch->idempleado;
            $_SESSION["empleado"] = $fetch->empleado;
            $_SESSION["tipo_documento"] = $fetch->tipo_documento;
            $_SESSION["tipo_usuario"] = $fetch->tipo_usuario;
            $_SESSION["num_documento"] = $fetch->num_documento;
            $_SESSION["direccion"] = $fetch->direccion;
            $_SESSION["telefono"] = $fetch->telefono;
            $_SESSION["foto"] = $fetch->foto;
            $_SESSION["logo"] = $fetch->logo;
            $_SESSION["email"] = $fetch->email;
            $_SESSION["login"] = $fetch->login;
            $_SESSION["razon_social"] = $fetch->razon_social;

            $_SESSION["idempresa"] = $fetch->idempresa;
            $_SESSION["Nombre_empresa"] = $fetch->Empresa;

            $_SESSION["mnu_almacen"] = $fetch->mnu_almacen;
            $_SESSION["mnu_compras"] = $fetch->mnu_compras;
            $_SESSION["mnu_ventas"] = $fetch->mnu_ventas;
            $_SESSION["mnu_mantenimiento"] = $fetch->mnu_mantenimiento;
            $_SESSION["mnu_seguridad"] = $fetch->mnu_seguridad;
            $_SESSION["mnu_consulta_compras"] = $fetch->mnu_consulta_compras;
            $_SESSION["mnu_consulta_ventas"] = $fetch->mnu_consulta_ventas;
            $_SESSION["mnu_admin"] = $fetch->mnu_admin;
            $_SESSION["superadmin"] = $fetch->superadmin;

        }

        echo json_encode($fetch);

        break;

            case "IngresarPanel" :
            $_SESSION["idusuario"] = $_POST["idusuario"];
            $_SESSION["idsucursal"] = $_POST["idsucursal"];
            $_SESSION["idempleado"] = $_POST["idempleado"];
            $_SESSION["superadmin"] = "A";

            $_SESSION["empleado"] = $_POST["empleado"];
            $_SESSION["tipo_documento"] = $_POST["tipo_documento"];
            $_SESSION["tipo_usuario"] = $_POST["tipo_usuario"];
            $_SESSION["num_documento"] = $_POST["num_documento"];
            $_SESSION["direccion"] = $_POST["direccion"];
            $_SESSION["telefono"] = $_POST["telefono"];
            $_SESSION["foto"] = $_POST["foto"];
            $_SESSION["logo"] = $_POST["logo"];
            $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["email"];
            $_SESSION["login"] = $_POST["login"];
            $_SESSION["sucursal"] = $_POST["razon_social"];

            $_SESSION["idempresa"] = $_POST["idempresa"];
            $_SESSION["Nombre_empresa"] = $_POST["Empresa"];

            $_SESSION["mnu_almacen"] = $_POST["mnu_almacen"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_compras"] = $_POST["mnu_compras"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_ventas"] = $_POST["mnu_ventas"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_mantenimiento"] = $_POST["mnu_mantenimiento"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_seguridad"] = $_POST["mnu_seguridad"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_consulta_compras"] = $_POST["mnu_consulta_compras"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_consulta_ventas"] = $_POST["mnu_consulta_ventas"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_admin"] = $_POST["mnu_admin"];
            $_SESSION["alerta"] = $_POST["alerta"];
                break;

            case "IngresarPanelSuperAdmin" :

            $_SESSION["idusuario"] = $_POST["idusuario"];
            $_SESSION["idsucursal"] = $_POST["idsucursal"];
            $_SESSION["idempleado"] = $_POST["idempleado"];
            $_SESSION["superadmin"] = $_POST["estadoAdmin"];
            $_SESSION["empleado"] = $_POST["empleado"];
            $_SESSION["idempresa"] = $idempresa;
            $_SESSION["tipo_documento"] = $_POST["tipo_documento"];
            $_SESSION["tipo_usuario"] = $_POST["tipo_usuario"];
            $_SESSION["num_documento"] = $_POST["num_documento"];
            $_SESSION["direccion"] = $_POST["direccion"];
            $_SESSION["telefono"] = $_POST["telefono"];
            $_SESSION["foto"] = $_POST["foto"];
            $_SESSION["logo"] = $_POST["logo"];
            $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["email"];
            $_SESSION["login"] = $_POST["login"];
            $_SESSION["sucursal"] = $_POST["razon_social"];

            $_SESSION["idempresa"] = $_POST["idempresa"];
            $_SESSION["Nombre_empresa"] = $_POST["Empresa"];

            $_SESSION["mnu_almacen"] = $_POST["mnu_almacen"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_compras"] = $_POST["mnu_compras"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_ventas"] = $_POST["mnu_ventas"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_mantenimiento"] = $_POST["mnu_mantenimiento"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_seguridad"] = $_POST["mnu_seguridad"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_consulta_compras"] = $_POST["mnu_consulta_compras"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_consulta_ventas"] = $_POST["mnu_consulta_ventas"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_admin"] = $_POST["mnu_admin"];
            $_SESSION["alerta"] = $_POST["alerta"];
                break;

                    break;

                case "IngresoEmpleado" :

            $_SESSION["idusuario"] = $_POST["idusuario"];
            $_SESSION["idsucursal"] = $_POST["idsucursal"];
            $_SESSION["idempleado"] = $_POST["idempleado"];
            $_SESSION["superadmin"] = "A";

            $_SESSION["empleado"] = $_POST["empleado"];
            $_SESSION["tipo_documento"] = $_POST["tipo_documento"];
            $_SESSION["tipo_usuario"] = $_POST["tipo_usuario"];
            $_SESSION["num_documento"] = $_POST["num_documento"];
            $_SESSION["direccion"] = $_POST["direccion"];
            $_SESSION["telefono"] = $_POST["telefono"];
            $_SESSION["foto"] = $_POST["foto"];
            $_SESSION["logo"] = $_POST["logo"];
            $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["email"];
            $_SESSION["login"] = $_POST["login"];
            $_SESSION["sucursal"] = $_POST["razon_social"];

            $_SESSION["idempresa"] = $_POST["idempresa"];
            $_SESSION["Nombre_empresa"] = $_POST["Empresa"];

            $_SESSION["mnu_almacen"] = $_POST["mnu_almacen"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_compras"] = $_POST["mnu_compras"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_ventas"] = $_POST["mnu_ventas"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_mantenimiento"] = $_POST["mnu_mantenimiento"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_seguridad"] = $_POST["mnu_seguridad"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_consulta_compras"] = $_POST["mnu_consulta_compras"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_consulta_ventas"] = $_POST["mnu_consulta_ventas"];
            $_SESSION["mnu_admin"] = $_POST["mnu_admin"];
            $_SESSION["alerta"] = $_POST["alerta"];

                break;
```

Desde local me funciona perfectamente, inicia sesión normalmente y puedo utilizar el sistema con normalidad... el problema esta en que lo he subido a un host para chequear algunas cosas y ver más o menos como funcionaba y pues no he podido ingresar, no hace absolutamente nada.

Se que subir aplicaciones web en hosting gratuitos no es lo mejor pero solo lo hago por prueba, ya he usado el mismo host antes. He configurado la base de datos bien, pues ya lo he chequeado como mil veces. La consola no me ningún error, no me muestra nada.

No entiendo por qué no puedo acceder.

¿Alguna ayuda o sugerencia que puedan darme a este problema?

Inspector de elementos: Sección Network...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: revisaste tanto el log de javascript como el de PHP? ninguno te dice nada?

Comment: ninguno me dice nada, absolutamente nada. Ni un mensaje de error, nada.

Comment: puedes entrar en "Inspeccionar elemento" y en la pestaña "Red" o "Network" comprobar si se están cargando los scripts y el archivo PHP? Eso tal vez ayude a encontrar más rápido el error

Comment: edite la pregunta...Coloque una imagen de la pestaña Network del inspector de elementos, para que se pueda ver mejor.

Comment: no se está cargando el jQuery, en dónde lo estás cargando'

Comment: he editado la pregunta, agregue el código completo del archivo index.html, ahi agregre la parte donde se llama a la libreria jquery

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78662/discussion-between-acentellao17-and-rolandf).

Comment: ¿`public` es una carpeta en el host gratuito? ¿Por qué no pruebas un código parecido, pero sin usar bases de datos? Puede que el hosting tenga algunas restricciones.

Comment: la carpeta public es una carpeta propia del sistema donde estan alojados los archivos js y css... probare tu sugerencia a ver que tal me va...

Comment: probé haciendo lo que indicaba, utilice un archivo parecido al archivo UsuarioAjax.php pero evitando hacer conexion con base de datos, simplemente recibiendo los datos y enviando una respuesta simple que me permita en el lado del cliente redirigir a una pagina que he creado donde hay un boton que permite cerrar la sesión y volver al index, pero igual no ha funcionado, sigue el mismo problema, al darle click a iniciar sesion no hace nada.

Comment: Le pude encontrar solución al problema. Me puse en contacto con el servicio de soporte tecnico del hosting y al parecer era la versión de PHP que tenia configurada el host. Se cambió a un par de versiones anteriores y funcionó la aplicación perfectamente. Gracias por sus aportes a la busqueda de la solución a mi problema.